# Batch interrupted with 'Aborted by user' error

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I have a batch class scheduled to run periodically, but seems that for some unknown reason, it gets aborted(Under Setup ->  Apex jobs, Error: 'Aborted by user'). I know that the error means, that "someone" aborted it, but I'm 99% sure that no other has executed an abort operation on this batch and we as a team have contacted with SFDC support, and they haven't replyed yet.

I'm sorry that I can't give any further dettails, because it's really weird as an error.

Please any clue, on what can be done towards this, rather than knowing on what has happened, because is almost a mistery.

Thanks guys, in advance!

Comment: one post here https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000ApPrIAK suggests a timeout would generate this error; same here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13794/can-an-already-running-batch-job-abort-automatically

Comment: Thanks for adressing those posts, but there still was no concrete solution to this. Was just a narrow justification about an internal timeout from SFDC, durin the query of the batch.

Comment: If you create a case with Salesforce, they will likely tell you that the query in the `start` method is exceeding the time permitted. I would look into your `start` method query first.

Comment: Yeah, we've thought of that. And actually there are already, some cases, upon this issue, and SFDC, gives the same explanation. The problem is, that this error happens once in a while, and not always. Nonetheless, the number of the records to work on, are pretty much the same, in the cases when it goes in error, and in the cases that doesn't.

Comment: It will likely depend on server load, query execution time can differ based on the amount of activity, if its happening even sometimes I would advise reviewing your query.

Comment: Yes, but, isn't the server capacity/resource that I use, somehow, isolated, from the other entities that also use it? I mean, multi-tenancy, is ensured by SFDC right? 
However, any idea over any optimisation that could be implemented?

Comment: We were told that a batch that was running for years without change that began to produce this error was due to too many records being in the recycle bin. So we created a process to empty the recycle bin daily and it still occurred. SF does not have an answer for this and keeps telling us to do the same thing and we keep getting the error. I wish they would fix it. Funny thing is the query in the start method took 0.56 seconds so I doubt it was the issue. Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

It happened in my org also. It can be because of below reasons.

1) Query in the start of batch is taking more than 10 minutes to run.(Previously it was 2 minutes).

2) In my case it was because of some permission issue. Batch is triggered from another class. If I run the class as "System Administrator", it is working fine. But when another user with permission to all the classes, run the batch it is failing. Yet to find out the exact reason.

Please check below Links,

[Can an already running batch job abort automatically?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13794/can-an-already-running-batch-job-abort-automatically/67243#67243)

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000ApPrIAK